# JS function to format money works bad after 999,99 (2 decimals)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var tmp = parseInt($('.'+auctionId2+' .bidCount').html());
$('.'+auctionId2+' .bidCount').html(tmp+1);

var tmp1 = $('.'+auctionId2+' .productValue').html();
tmp1 = tmp1.replace(',', '@');
tmp1 = tmp1.replace('.', ',');
tmp1 = tmp1.replace('@', '.');
tmp1 = parseFloat(tmp1);
tmp1 = tmp1 - bid_price;
var tmp2 = formatMoney(tmp1);
$('.'+auctionId2+' .auctionSavings').html(tmp2 + "€");

function formatMoney(amount, decimalCount = 2, decimal = ",", thousands = ".") {
try {
decimalCount = Math.abs(decimalCount);
decimalCount = isNaN(decimalCount) ? 2 : decimalCount;

const negativeSign = amount < 0 ? "-" : "";

let i = parseInt(amount = Math.abs(Number(amount) || 0).toFixed(decimalCount)).toString();
let j = (i.length > 3) ? i.length % 3 : 0;

return negativeSign + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousands : '') + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousands) + (decimalCount ? decimal + Math.abs(amount - i).toFixed(decimalCount).slice(2) : "");
} catch (e) {
console.log(e)
}
};
```

These function update in real time the price, its works good until 999,99 after 1.000,00 it always show as result a negative no sense number.

In front-end is showed in this lines

```
 <h2 class="auctionSavings"><?php echo $number->currency($auction['Auction']['savings']['price'], $appConfigurations['currency']);?></h2>
```

And the JS update the price in real time, working good when prices are lower than 999,99 and bad if prices are higher than 1.000,99

The prices always have 2 decimals, the decimals are separated by "," and thousand and hundreds by "."

Where its the problem in the function?

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you don't use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)?

Comment: these its the default script method